# IF condition in MVC3 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have added IF condition in MVC3 view but its not working:

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel>   
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome Student";
}

<h2>Welcome 
@Context.User.Identity.Name
</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("[Sign Out]", "SignOut", "Student")
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register Courses", "registerCourses", "Course")</li>
</ul>

<h3>Pending Courses</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>RollNumber
    </th>
    <th>Course Code
    </th>
    <th>Course Name
    </th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>

@foreach (StudentRegistrationPortal.Models.CourseRegisterModel modelValue in Model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelValue.Course.Code))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Context.User.Identity.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelValue.Course.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelValue.Course.Name)
        </td>
        <td>Pending
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}

</table>
```

It gives following error while executing IF statement:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The purpose of IF condition to confirm that `modelValue.Course.Code` value is not empty string or null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely that `Course` itself is null. You would need to check for both:

```
if (modelValue.Course!=null &&   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelValue.Course.Code))
 {
 //etc
 }
```